# C3 Line graph Y-axis lables are not coming for particular values?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, c3.js

Below is my code to get the chart.

When I specify the y axis labels dynamically, then the Y-axis label is not showing in the C3 chart:

```
var chart = c3.generate({
data: {
    columns: [
        ['sample', 291.581, 291.311, 291.281, 291.81, 291.51]
    ]
},
axis : {
    y : {
        tick: {
          count:4,
          values: [100,200,300,400]
        }
    }
}
});

Y axis labels are nort showing?[![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

Comment: why don't you use the label property of the Axis as mentioned in charts like they have show .... here is the url
http://c3js.org/samples/axes_label.html

Comment: I want to set count of only 4 ticks,For other data its showing Ex: - ['sample', 291.581, 291.311, 291.281, 291.81, 291.51]     but onLy when i mentioned sample data will come that tim ey-Axis not showing

Comment: you mean to add y axis with the value you are trying to put on chart that are  100,200,300 and 400 right .?

Comment: In above code i have values Ex :-  ['sample', 291.581, 291.311, 291.281, 291.81, 291.51]  For this i am not getting any y axis labels But if i change any one value to Fixed value Ex : - ['sample', 300, 291.311, 291.281, 291.81, 291.51] like this then i am getting Y axis labels  ,I got this happened  because i am setting Y-axis values as y : {
        tick: {
          count:4,
          values: [100,200,300,400]
        }
    }

Comment: now got the point let me check if i can find any thing helpfu;